# Zurb Foundation's javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Currently working on `Rails 4.2.6`, installed [foundation-rails](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails) gem, follow all the instruction. Now it include a bunch of javscript and stylesheet files in application,

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require jquery_sortable
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

but when i try to use some components having javascript in it, it does not work. I tried this drop-down from foundation's docs

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-dropdown="drop">Link Dropdown &raquo;</a>
<ul id="drop" class="[tiny small medium large content]f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

It just give me some links without any working drop-down and an error in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined(…)
(anonymous function)    @   foundation.core.self-f55f82f….js?body=1:197
```

Also alert messages are not working properly either,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <% flag = name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>
        <div data-alert class="alert-box <%= flag %> radius">
          <strong><%= flag == 'success' ? 'Yay!' : 'Error' %></strong>
          - <%= msg %>
          <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

It shows an alert box with message but it won't close by clicking on x button or link and for that it don't give any error messages.

Comment: I haven't tried `jquery.turbolinks` but could it be thats its actually causing more harm than good? I would try removing it and calling `$(document).on('page:load', function(){ $(this).foundation(); });`

Comment: This will bind the handler so that foundation is reinitialized when the page is reloaded.

Comment: @max Thank for your response, I tried what you said but no major change still drop-down is not working, but now there is no error in the console.

Comment: The class attribute for your dropdown looks wrong - `[tiny small medium large content]f-dropdown` - should be something like `tiny small medium large content f-dropdown`- also what kind of dropdown are you trying to create? That looks nothing like the current docs.

Comment: I am following [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown.html) and i am just trying to create any kind of drop-down not a particular, i was just curious that why its no working. And also by adding `$(document).on('page:load', function(){ $(this).foundation(); });` my responsive nav bar is not working properly.

Comment: Actually you were right i was following wrong docs or maybe old ones, now i am following foundation 6 and after a little tweak everything works. And it all work with `jquery.turbolinks` and `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` Thanks @max for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked out. You can answer your own question in that case so to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out i was following the wrong docs, i am currently using 6.2.1 and was following the docs of 5.5.3. If you have a problem like that make sure you are following the right docs.